# Divide a number into equal values and push to an array

Tags: javascript, function

I need to divide a number equally and push the values on the array. I'm using 100 as an example,
but when I do it, it goes [28, 24, 24, 24], and I need it to be [25, 25, 25, 25]

```
const divide = () => {
  var number = 100
  var n = 4

  var values = []
  while(number > 0 && n > 0){
    var a = Math.floor(number / n / 4) * 4
    number -= a
    n--
    values.push(a)
  }

  console.log(values)
}
```

Comment: why do you divide and multiply by 4? No need to re-calc many times, just divide 100 by n and push that result n times.

Comment: (n/4) *4 forces it to be a multiple of 4, which 25 isn't

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have couple of issues in your code, decreasing the n means that the next loop the divided value will change.

Here is an updated version that works correctly:

```js
    const divide = (number = 100, n = 4) => {
      const values = [];
      let times = n;
      while(times > 0){
        values.push(Math.floor(number / n));
        times--;
      }
      return values;
    }
    
    console.log(divide());
```

To explain how this should work, in order to get the same number in the arrays nth times, n should not be changed.
So we are copying its value to a local variable that is hten used to create / control the loop.
Each time the loop runs we divide the target number with n - for all of the iterations so we get the same number and its always 1/4 of the 100.
Hope this helps ..

Comment: There's one case where dividing 100 by 3, the expected result is [ 33.34, 33.33, 33.33 ], but I get [33.33, 33.33, 33.33], do you know what could be the cause of this difference?

Comment: It cannot have different values as we always divide same number with the same value. If you wanna have that then the algorithm must change. Instead of what we have now you would need to keep additionally rest variable that is containing the rest of the initial number decreased by the iteration division.  Something like this (this is just a meta code to give you an idea) :
var rest = rest ? rest : number;
rest = rest / times;
and then use this rest

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly:

```
const divide = (num = 100, n = 4) => new Array(n).fill(num / n);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Math.floor()` function returns the largest integer less than or equal to a given number, in your code this functions make the result incorrect

##### this is a correct code :

```
const divide = () => {
  var number = 100
  var n = 4

  var values = []
  for(int i=1;i<=4;i++){
    values.push(a/4)
  }

  console.log(values)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version of doing it:

```js
const divide = (num = 100, n = 4) => {
  const f=Math.floor(num/n);
  return [...Array(n)].map((_,i)=>i-n+1?f:num-i*f);
}
    
console.log(divide());
console.log(divide(100,3));
```